# How to download folder from AzureML notebook folder to local or blob storage?

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-machine-learning-service

I saved file to the same directory using (./folder_name) when I use AzureML jupyter. Now how can I download to my local machine or blob storage?

The folder have a lot of files and sub-directory in it, which I scraped online. So it is not realistic to save one by one.

```
file_path = "./"

for i in target_key_word:
    tem_str = i.replace(' ', '+')
    dir_name = file_path + i
    if not os.path.exists(dir_name):
        os.mkdir(dir_name)
    else:    
        print("Directory " , dir_name ,  " already exists")
```

Answer (score 13):

Appreciate this is an old question but for anyone else with this questions this is how I did it.

1. Open a new terminal window in your Azure ML Notebooks homepage.
2. Zip up the entire directory with:

   ```
    zip -r myfiles.zip .
   ```
3. Refresh the folder explorer and download the zip file.

Comment: this answer was very smart, thank you a lot.

Comment: Most probably this is obvious for every Azure ML user, but as this was the first time for me using this software. You need to create a compute, and obviously, if you have many files it is faster to zip if you have more cpu cores :) 
Thank you for the answer, it was usful.

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking how you could download all your files and folders from the Notebooks GUI of Azure ML Studio, I wish there was a straightforward way to do so. As far as I know, you could do the following for now:

1. You have to download [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) and navigate to the blob storage linked to your ML workspace in the Azure portal (you can find the precise blob storage account by navigating to the overview section of your ML workspace).
2. After you open the linked blob storage from the resource group, navigate to the overview section where you should select `Open in Explorer`.
3. Once the Storage Explorer is open you can link the Azure blob storage by connecting it to the Explorer (which is pretty straightforward, you just have to fetch the key from the Access Keys section).
4. After your storage account is linked, navigate to the `File Shares` folder and find the folder prefixed `code-`. This is where you will find all your files and folders, which you can download to your local in bulk.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you would like to download the project files :

You could do one of the below :

From the project page, click the "Download Project" button to download all the files of a given project.

**OR**

1. Go to Azure Notebooks and sign in.
2. From your public profile page, select My Projects at the top of the
   page.
3. My Projects link on the top of the browser window
4. Select the project.
5. Click the download **Download** button to trigger a zip file download
   that contains all of your project files.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for downloading Notebooks is to go through the azure ML studio UI to "Edit in VS Code." Once you have it open in VS Code, right click the folder and there is an option "Download"
You can save these files to local and then re-upload as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
from azureml.core import Workspace
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
import os

# Load Azure ML workspace
ws = Workspace.from_config()

# Azure Blob Storage connection string
blob_connection_string = "<your_blob_connection_string>"
container_name = "<your_container_name>"

# Folder to be copied
folder_path = "<folder_path>"

# Create a blob service client
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(blob_connection_string)

# Create a container client
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

# List files in the folder
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
    for file in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
        # Upload each file to the blob storage container
        with open(file_path, "rb") as data:
            blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(file_path.replace(folder_path, ""))
            blob_client.upload_blob(data)
```